# Managed Metadata not displaying on 1st page load

Tags: content-type, page-layout, managed-metadata, enterprise-wiki, managed-metadata-column

I'm utilizing SharePoint 2013 (on-premises), and attempting to add a managed metadata field to a custom page layout for an enterprise Wikipedia site. However, the data isn't loading on the page until the 2nd or 3rd page refresh. Steps taken:

1. Created three Custom Site Columns - Company, Dept, Location. Each
   are of type Managed Metadata (and tied to a different term set).
2. Created and published a Custom Content Type - called ExpandedWikiPage. It's parent
   Content Type is the (OOB) Enterprise Wiki Page
3. Added the Custom Site Columns to the ExpandedWikiPage.
4. Created and published a Custom Html Page Layout called TrackingPage.
   AssociatedContent Type: ExpandedWikiPage
5. Used the Design Manager to generate a HTML Snippets for each custom
   site column (Company, Dept, Location). Added the snippets to the
   TrackingPage.html (custom page layout HTML file). Published it.

When creating a new page in the enterprise wiki site, utilizing the ExpandedWiki (custom content type) and TrackingPage (custom page layout), I'm able to populate the custom managed metadata columns (Company, Dept, Location). However the page only appears as expected after refreshing it several times. The custom managed metadata column do not show on the first page load. But does appear after multiple page refreshes. The Div tag is generated but is populated with "&nbsp;       ", until refresh. After refreshing, the div tag contains data instead of spacing.

Why is the data not available/populating on the first page load? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Place the custom page layout on the site collection root (with the custom site columns, custom content type, etc.) and this is no longer an issue.